Flow of marked packets in Linux network stack
Summary:
My question is regarding the flow of marked packets in the network stack.
Here is what i have done:

I have marked packets in the mangle table using the OUTPUT chain.
I have also added a tun interface and a new routing table.
I also added a rule (using ip rule) for marked packets to use the created routing table.

Now my question:
Before I explain the question, I have to mention that my setup is working and this is not a question of how to do it, rather it's a question of how is it working. :)
According to this picture which is depicted in this article, packets from the local process will first be routed and then entered in the OUTPUT chain of the netfilters. This means that the packet gets marked after the routing process has been finished. So how does the packet reaches to the tun interface?

Does it go out one interface and enter another?
Does everything happens locally?
Or sth else completely?

Here is the command i have used:
# ip commands
ip tuntap add mode tun dev testtun
ip addr add 10.20.30.40/24 dev testtun
echo "20 test" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip link set dev testtun up
ip route add default via 10.20.30.1 table test
ip rule add fwmark 12 table tes

# iptables command:
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m cgroup --cgroup 0x10f2c -j MARK --set-mark 12

I'm using net_cls controller and cgroups v1 to isolate a process with classid of 0x10f2c. Again this setup is working and i have achieved what i was looking for and i'm only stuck in the how is it working part.
I would appreciate any help regarding this question <3.
